# Python: Sending Raw XML via Suds (jurko)

Tags: python, xml, suds

I'm interfacing with a SOAP API, wherein a particular method requires a raw XML string as a parameter. Like so:

```
import suds.client as sudscl

client = sudscl.Client('http://host/ws.wsdl', location='http://host/ws')

session = 'test123'
options = '<rawXML><Item>Foobar</Item></rawXML>'

result = client.service.ExecuteSearch(session, options)
```

Pretty straight-forward. However, suds HTML-encodes the XML string I just sent in, like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://host/ws">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns1:Body>
     <ns0:ExecuteSearch>
        <ns0:session>test123</ns0:session>
        <ns0:options>
          &lt;rawXML&rt;&lt;Item&rt;Foobar&lt;/Item&rt;&lt;/rawXML&rt;
        </ns0:options>
     </ns0:ExecuteSearch>
   </ns1:Body>
 </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Boo! Is there any way to get suds to pass in the XML string un-altered?

Thanks!

Comment: Does [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21800232/1167750) help?

Comment: @summea - Unfortunately, no.  
  
1. This would require me to build and then pass in the entire SOAP message, when in fact I just want to pass in *one parameter* unmodified (not build the entire XML message from scratch).  
  
2. __inject isn't working for me anyway (_TypeError: ExecuteSearch() got an unexpected keyword argument '__inject'_).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, got it.

```
from suds.sax.text import Raw
import suds.client as sudscl

client = sudscl.Client('http://host/ws.wsdl', location='http://host/ws')

session = 'test123'
options = Raw('<rawXML><Item>Foobar</Item></rawXML>')

result = client.service.ExecuteSearch(session, options)
```